# what does it mean that my static library symbols are defined with an address 0

Tags: c, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm trying to componentize my build into multiple static libraries, and link them together into one shared library. I'm losing symbols from the final .so file. One strange behavior I noticed is that the symbols in one of the static libraries define a bunch of symbols with an address of 0. According to the nm man page T means that a symbol is defined and exported. What does address 0 mean if the symbols are defined?

```
0000000000000000 T _ZN16djinni_generated19NativeRendererStateC1Ev
0000000000000000 T _ZN16djinni_generated19NativeRendererStateC2Ev
0000000000000000 T _ZN16djinni_generated19NativeRendererStateD1Ev
0000000000000000 T _ZN16djinni_generated19NativeRendererStateD2Ev
0000000000000000 T _ZN16djinni_generated20NativePlatformObject5toCppEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject
0000000000000000 T _ZN16djinni_generated20NativePlatformObject7fromCppEP7_JNIEnvRKNSt6__ndk110shared_ptrIN5ALYCE14PlatformObjectEEE
0000000000000000 T _ZN16djinni_generated20NativePlatformObjectC1Ev
0000000000000000 T _ZN16djinni_generated20NativePlatformObjectC2Ev
0000000000000000 T _ZN16djinni_generated20NativePlatformObjectD1Ev
0000000000000000 T _ZN16djinni_generated20NativePlatformObjectD2Ev
```

Comment: The addresses can't be known until everything is linked together. The compiler literally puts 0 as a placeholder. Once everything is linked the symbols will have addresses unless they are referenced from other shared libs. Then the runtime linker/loader will fix up address locations.

Comment: Oh, thanks for explaining. Do you want to make that into an answer?

Comment: No I'm good. Just saw this and wanted to help a little.